# return output parameter in sql server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Here condition is true then it return true otherwise return false

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spAppliedJobOrnot

    --Here job is already applied then it return true otherwise return false
    @check bit OUTPUT,
    @UserId numeric,
    @JobId numeric

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    if exists (SELECT 1 FROM StudentInbox_Activities WHERE JobId=@JobId and StudentId=@UserId and 
    JobAppliedDate is not null)
        BEGIN
        SET @check=1  --The job is applied so check=true
        END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @check=0;
    END
END
GO
```

Here how to get the @check value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have `@check` as output parameter, you can get this value from your application too.
If it is in C#, you can use something like the following,

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_NAME");
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", param1);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", param2);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@check", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters["@check"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
return Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@check"].Value);
```

Answer (score 3):

When using OUTPUT params, you need to return the value in the calling statement.

Have a lok at this example

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6a2e6/1)

Procedure to do whatever

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FOO(@BAR INT OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @BAR = -1
END;
```

And then calling statement

```
DECLARE @TADA INT = 0
EXEC FOO @TADA OUTPUT
SELECT @TADA
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the following code after your if- end statement, before procedure end statement

```
select @check
```

Then run the procedure.

Maybe [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111553/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/062905-1.aspx) might be helpful for your problem about ASP.Net.

Comment: I'm using asp.net how can i get @check value in asp.net

Comment: That's not how output parameters work. See astander's answer for the SQL side and BAdmin's for the client side.

Comment: @StevePettifer If we just want to check output, then it is fine (as I thought). Then again question was asked about using the output with asp.net. So the link. I've modified the tag to include asp.net.

Comment: It's not though - doing `select @check` in the procedure would return a single value in a single record, not a value in an output parameter. whilst the question wasn't all that explicit it was clear that this was what the OP was asking as his proc was functionally correct. Your answer does not fulfill any of the requirements.